# Getting "Could not find application" error when running "jhipster heroku"

Tags: jhipster, okta

Getting Could not find application error as follows:

```
$ jhipster heroku                                                   
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
INFO! Executing jhipster:heroku
Heroku configuration is starting
✖ Could not find application: geonamesservice
✖ Run the generator again to create a new application.
identical pom.xml
    force .yo-rc.json
INFO! Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
```

Does anyone know why I am getting the "Could not find application" error?

Comment: The code is looking up the heroku app named "geonamesservice" and not finding it.  Try deleting `herokuAppName` from your `.yo-rc.json` and running `jhipster heroku` again

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I will try and get back with you.

Comment: Yes, Jon, that worked! Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your app was not found from the heroku command `heroku apps:info --json`, which [runs here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/355fb16ea2d5feb08408083f1aaddfdb13bc461c/generators/heroku/index.js#L114-L139).

The fix is to remove the `herokuAppName` key in `.yo-rc.json` and re-run `jhipster heroku`.

- If you have an existing Heroku app using that name and want to re-deploy it, use the same app name.
- If you do not have an existing Heroku app using that name, you can still deploy under that name, or choose a new name.

There is a bug in the generator code where the config is not cleared automatically, requiring you to manually edit `.yo-rc.json`.  This is fixed in [pull request 13039](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/13039) which will be part of v7 of JHipster.